# How can I hide interactive console in debug mode in PyDev Eclipse?

Tags: python, pydev

How can I remove interactive console from debug logging in PyDev - it takes place and not helps. I normal run there is no such console and it is o.k.

[image]

Comment: Why people gives -1 for question still I have no idea - some feedback is need?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. Hopefully my answer is helpful to you if not to them.

Comment: and how do I avoid getting those PyDev debugger logs of form `pydev debugger: warning: ...` in the eclipse console? I get a lot of them when I run code in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn it off by clicking the icon that looks like a console in the view toolbar, as the arrow below shows:

[image: where to click in view]

Comment: I want to to open the prompt but I'm unable to find this icon on the menu bar, how can I open it?

Comment: @user2361174 if you don't have the icon, you don't have the ability to open the prompt. Either this means you have too old version of PyDev or your console is not attached to a debug session?

Comment: You're right, I had PyDev 2.8.2, I updated it to 4.5.4 (later versions of it doesn't show up at all) and now I have it!

Comment: @user2361174 If you mean PyDev in its entirety does not show up see release notes: ["Important PyDev now requires Java 8 and Eclipse 4.5 onwards."](http://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html)

Comment: and how do I avoid getting those PyDev debugger logs of form `pydev debugger: warning: ...` in the eclipse console? I get a lot of them when I run code in debug mode.